# MySQL Combining multiple tables in a view

Tags: mysql, view, sql-view

I have 3 tables that I want to be able to combine in a view:

```
tblContent:
strTitle        | txtContent
content 1 title | content 1 content
content 2 title | content 2 content
content 3 title | content 3 content 

tblNews
news_title      | news_content
news 1 title    | news 1 content
news 2 title    | news 2 content

tblTradeMembers
company_title   | company_content
trade 1 title   | trade 1 content
trade 2 title   | trade 2 content
trade 3 title   | trade 3 content
trade 4 title   | trade 4 content
```

So basically, I want to map the contents of each of these tables to my single result view which I am then able to query which will be like:

```
title           | content             | from
content 1 title | content 1 content   | tblContent
content 2 title | content 2 content   | tblContent
content 3 title | content 3 content   | tblContent
news 1 title    | news 1 content      | tblNews
news 2 title    | news 2 content      | tblNews
trade 1 title   | trade 1 content     | tblTradeMembers
trade 2 title   | trade 2 content     | tblTradeMembers
trade 3 title   | trade 3 content     | tblTradeMembers
trade 4 title   | trade 4 content     | tblTradeMembers
```

So I can do:

```
select * from custom_view WHERE content LIKE "%3%"
```

Is this achievable and how do I go about it?

Comment: do you have any ID or PK-FK in the tables?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is no relation between the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT strTitle AS 'TITLE', txtContent AS 'Content', 'tblContent' AS 'From'
 UNION     
 SELECT news_title AS 'TITLE', news_content AS 'Content', 'tblNews' AS 'From'
 UNION
 SELECT company_title AS 'TITLE', company_content AS 'Content', 'tblTradeMembers' AS 'From'
```

This will club all the records in your view

Comment: that set me in the right direction, thank you. It runs pretty slow but it does what I need it to

Comment: As there is no relation among the tables we have to go for UNION otherwise using join we can improve the perfomance.